# Filter ListView using EditText error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have this code for the listview i want to filter:

```
private EditText mySearchView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter;
private ListView listView;
```

And:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

                  Animation pushLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.jump_no_fade);
                  view.startAnimation(pushLeftIn);

            }
            });

            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });

            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);

            mySearchView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchText);

            mySearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CallActivity.this.friendsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

I have tried making the edittext called mySearchView filter the listview, when typed in, but when i open the app and type inside the edittext nothing happens, what is wrong with the code or how could i modify it?

I also get this logcat error when i load up the listview:

```
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640): Bad thing happened
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at    com.example.test.CallActivity$1.onComplete(CallActivity.java:127)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at com.example.test.CallActivity$1.onComplete(CallActivity.java:1)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.GetAction$1.onCompleted(GetAction.java:48)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1670)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-02 16:23:47.075: E/com.example.test.CallActivity(27640):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never wire up mySearchView from an XML entity, nor do you create it prior to using it. I assume you haven't posted all of your code - you ought to be getting an NPE on your addTextChangedListener declaration.

Comment: Yep i get npe on it, i added the logcat to question aswell

Comment: right, so what you need is to define the View by finding it.   Something like:   mySearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchview);

Comment: I have defined it but still get error :/ i updated answer with the code